# How to get vagrant to clone a Stash repo?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I am trying to get vagrant to clone a Stash repo at the end of the provision phase of a `vagrant up`

During a `vagrant up` I currently receive the following error:

```
   default: Running: inline script
==> default: Cloning into 'awesome_repo'...
==> default: Permission denied (publickey).
==> default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
==> default: 
==> default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
==> default: and the repository exists.
```

I have set my project to use vagrant's public and private key:   `config.ssh.insert_key = false`

I have placed the `insecure_private_key` file in the ~/.ssh/ folder on the guest machine. And I have placed the vagrant public key into my Stash Repo.

For some reason when I get to that stage in the provisioner I receive the above error. I have also tried these steps by `vagrant ssh` into the guest machine then proceeding to `git clone` and I am receiving the same error.

Here is part of my `Vagrantfile` SSH configurations:

```
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.pty = true
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't paste the whole `Vagrantfile`, but let me guess, you should use `https://` than `git://` to clone the repository.

Comment: why should I use https? that would request my username and password instead of using the ssh public / private key for authentication. I wouldn't be able to automate cloning the repo.

Comment: try first, just save your time, if you don't like my solution, then fight with the problem :-) otherwise, paste all in Vagrantfile for us to refer.